# Multiple geographical regions or multiple markets

Tags: drupal

In a Drupal site there are different contents for different regional audiences. I need to implement a language switcher like selector to change region/market.

How should I implement a market/region selector that works like the language selector in Drupal?

Switching a region along with a language should have impact on the URL, e.g the URL should change to example.com/ksa/ar, or example.com/ksa/en.

Can a subsite be the solution for regions?

Comment: For which Drupal version are you asking? The answer could change basing on the Drupal version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use drupal's location module:

http://drupal.org/project/location

Then just setup a redirect based on a users location.

Also there is an advantage in using sub sites, search engines see them as different websites so all your sub sites will be indexed. Where as sections in a folder structure are seen as one site so they will not be indexed.